# click link web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to practice writing VBA code, and I wrote this code to extract some data from this site, but I found something strange, which is when I query the internal text of the link in this way

```
?htmllink.innerText
DOE SBIR/STTR FY 2021 PHASE I RELEASE 2 | SBIR.gov
```

The text appears directly but when I query the text this way

```
?htmllinks.item(0).innertext

DOE SBIR/STTR FY 2021 PHASE I RELEASE 2 | SBIR.gov
```

A blank line appears before the text causing me a problem when I request to click on the link.

```
Sub testinterexplorer()
 
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://www.sbir.gov/#"
    
    Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set htmldoc = ie.Document
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
 
    Dim htmlsearch1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlsearch2  As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmllogin  As MSHTML.IHTMLButtonElement
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    y = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "m").End(xlUp).Row

    Set htmlsearch1 = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-search")(0)
    htmlsearch1.Click
    
    Dim r As Integer
    
    r = 0
    
    For i = 3 To y
    
        If Len(sh.Range("w" & i)) = 0 Then

            Set htmlsearch2 = htmldoc.getElementById("edit-search-block-form--2")
            htmlsearch2.Value = " "
            htmlsearch2.Value = sh.Range("m" & i).Value
            Set htmllogin = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(r)
  
            htmllogin.Click
            
            Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            
        End If
        
        Dim htmlpage As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim htmllinks As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim htmllink As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        '  Set htmllinks = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("gs-title").Length - 1
        Set htmllinks = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("gsc-thumbnail-inside")

        Dim l As Long
        Dim k As Long
        
        k = htmllinks.Length - 2
        
        For l = 0 To k
            'Set htmllink = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("gsc-thumbnail-inside").Item(l)
            Set htmllink = htmllinks.Item(l).getElementsByTagName("a").Item(0)
            
            Dim g$

            g = htmllink.innerText
            'g = htmllinks.Item(l).innerText
            ' g = Right(g, Len(g) - 2)
            If Right$(g, 3) = "..." Then g = Left$(g, Len(g) - 4)
    
            If Left$(sh.Range("m" & i).Value, Len(g)) = g And Len(g) > 0 Then
   
                htmllink.Click
                'htmllinks.Item(l).Click
    
            Else
                sh.Range("w" & i).Value = " not found "
                sh.Range("x" & i).Value = " not found "
                sh.Range("y" & i).Value = " not found "
                sh.Range("z" & i).Value = " not found "
                'Debug.Print htmllink.innerText
            End If
            
        Next
 
        r = 1
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally introduce that blank line manually? Also, in one case you are selecting for the parent div whereas the other you are selecting for the "expected" child anchor tag.

Comment: Do you need to simply capture all the results urls then visit each of them? Do you need to filter that list? Do you also need to capture the text for the parent divs?

Comment: I want to capture the url that matches the one I'm looking for

Comment: So you already know the url and are trying to see if is on page?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and knowing the reason for the question in the introduction to the topic